# Layout in SwiftUI with horizontal and vertical alignment

Tags: alignment, swiftui

I'm trying to accomplish this layout

[image: desired layout]

If I try HStack wrapped in VStack, I get this:

[image: HStack in VStack]

If I try VStack wrapped in HStack, I get this:

[image: VStack in HStack]

Is there a way to baseline align the text with the textfield and get standard spacing from the longest label to the start of the aligned textfields?

Comment: I was trying to do a very similar thing with SwiftUI the other day. The WWDC talk [Building Custom Views With SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/237/) covers some stuff on custom alignment behavior, which you might be able to exploit (look around the 21 minute mark). I could picture making a custom alignment guide along with an `HStack` wrapped in a `VStack` to get the alignment that you want.

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that part of the video, but I don't think it accomplishes what I need. Thanks!

Comment: insane that this isn't easy given how easy it is in UIKit

Answer (score 23, accepted):

not an expert here, but I managed to achieve the desired layout by (1) opting for the 2-`VStacks`-in-a-`HStack` alternative, (2) framing the external labels, (3) freeing them from their default vertical expansion constraint by assigning their `maxHeight = .infinity` and (4) fixing the height of the `HStack`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    let labels = ["Username", "Email", "Password"]

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(labels, id: \.self) { label in
                    Text(label)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .padding(.bottom, 4)
                }
            }

            VStack {
                ForEach(labels, id: \.self) { label in
                    TextField(label, text: self.$text)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                }
            }
            .padding(.leading)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }
}
```

Here is the resulting preview:

[image]

in order to account for the misaligned baselines of the external and internal labels (a collateral issue that is not related to this specific layout – see for instance [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57612762/swiftui-vertically-misaligned-text)) I manually added the padding

credits to [this website](https://netsplit.com/swiftui/) for enlightening me on the path to understanding
SwiftUI layout trickeries

Comment: This solution looks good. The only "hack" is the padding to get the text to line up with the TextField.

Comment: For some reason, the right side VStack uses a default spacing - looks like maybe 8 points, but the left side VStack has a spacing of 0. When I add in the spacing, the alignment of the Text to the TextField is a lot closer.

Comment: To add to this, I dont think this gives you the desired effect if the text field is more than one line high. The left labels center would NOT be aligned to the right labels center with this solution.

Comment: @tetotechy the website link reports Not Found.

Answer (score 9):

## SwiftUI Grids to the rescue!

Starting from iOS 16 you should use a [Grid](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grid) for this.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let labels = ["Username", "Email", "Password"]

    var body: some View {
        Grid {
            ForEach(labels, id: \.self) { label in
                GridRow {
                    Text(label)
                    TextField(label, text: .constant(""))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### iOS 13-15 legacy hack

You could use [kontiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7786555/kontiki)'s [geometry reader hack](https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/#Collaborating-Views) for this:

[image: SwiftUI live preview]

```
struct Column: View {
    @State private var height: CGFloat = 0
    @State var text = ""
    let spacing: CGFloat = 8
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: spacing) {
                Group {
                    Text("Hello world")
                    Text("Hello Two")
                    Text("Hello Three")
                }.frame(height: height)
            }.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
            VStack(spacing: spacing) {
                TextField("label", text: $text).bindHeight(to: $height)
                TextField("label 2", text: $text)
                TextField("label 3", text: $text)
            }.textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }.fixedSize().padding()
    }
}

extension View {
    func bindHeight(to binding: Binding<CGFloat>) -> some View {
        func spacer(with geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { binding.value = geometry.size.height }
            return Spacer()
        }
        return background(GeometryReader(content: spacer))
    }
}
```

We are only reading the height of the first TextField here and applying it three times on the three different Text Views, assuming that all TextFields have the same height. If your three TextFields have different heights or have appearing/disappearing verification labels that affect the individual heights, you can use the same technique but with three different height bindings instead.

**Why is this a bit of a hack?**

Because this solution will always first render the TextFields without the labels. During this render phase it will set the height of the Text labels and trigger another render. It would be more ideal to render everything in one layout phase.

Comment: it might be a hack but it seems like the only one that doesn't require constants, and actually delivers the layout requested.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this will work:

```
extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum MyAlignment: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in context: ViewDimensions) -> Length {
            context[.trailing]
        }
    }
    static let myAlignmentGuide = HorizontalAlignment(MyAlignment.self)
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var email: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .myAlignmentGuide) {
            HStack {
                Text("Username").alignmentGuide(.myAlignmentGuide, computeValue: { d in d[.trailing] })
                TextField($username)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .frame(maxWidth: 200)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Email")
                    .alignmentGuide(.myAlignmentGuide, computeValue: { d in d[.trailing] })
                TextField($email)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .frame(maxWidth: 200)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Password")
                    .alignmentGuide(.myAlignmentGuide, computeValue: { d in d[.trailing] })
                TextField($password)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .frame(maxWidth: 200)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With that code, I am able to achieve this layout:

[image: Aligned layout]

The caveat here is that I had to specify a max width for the `TextField`s. Left unconstrained, the layout system described in the WWDC talk I linked in the comments retrieves a size for the `TextField` *prior* to alignment happening, causing the `TextField` for email to extend past the end of the other two. I'm not sure how to address this in a way that will allow the `TextField`s to expand to the size of the containing view without going over...

Comment: Using a custom alignment guide shifts the position of the whole HStack, which is why you had to right align the labels to get it to look ok. But that's not the layout I need. Thanks!

Comment: This is clearly not the layout asked for.

Answer (score 1):

```
    HStack{
        Image(model.image)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 10, alignment: .leading)
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Second column ")
            Text("Second column -")
        }
        Spacer()
        Text("3rd column")
    }
```

1- first column - image

2- second column - two text

3- the float value

Spacer() - Play with Spacer() -> above example image and vstack remains together vertical align for all rows, just put spacer for the views you want to do in another vertical alignment / column
VStack(alignment: .leading.  - this is importent to make alignment start

Answer (score 0):

```
    var body: some View {

    VStack {
        HStack {
            Text("Username")
            Spacer()
            TextField($username)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .frame(maxWidth: 200)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .accentColor(.red)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        HStack {
            Text("Email")
            Spacer()
            TextField($email)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .frame(maxWidth: 200)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        HStack {
            Text("Password")
            Spacer()
            TextField($password)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .frame(maxWidth: 200)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
}
```

[image: This is the results of the above code. It use an HStack wrapped in a VStack and has the alignment you are trying to achieve]

Comment: Adjust the frame width to allow them to fill more space. I am not sure how that would look on larger screens though.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you have to solve for maxWidth for all permutations of screen size and text size (including localizations and dynamic type).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add fixed width and leading alignment. I've tested in Xcode 11.1 it's ok.

```swift
struct TextInputWithLabelDemo: View {
    @State var text = ""
    let labels = ["Username", "Email", "Password"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(labels, id: \.self) { label in
                HStack {
                    Text(label).frame(width: 100, alignment: .leading)
                    TextField(label, text: self.$text)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Below You can see what the issue when we use different `VStack` for `Text` and `TextField`. See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58389730/4067700)
[image]

## Updated 16 Oct 2019

A closer inspection of `Texts` and `TextFields` you can notice that they have different heights and it effects the positions of `Texts` relative to `TextFields` as you can see on the right side of the screenshot that `Password Text` is higher relative to `Password TextField` than the `Username Text` relative to `Username TextField`. 
I gave three ways to resolve this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58083886/4067700)

[image]

Comment: The problem with setting the width of the text to 100 is that it's not flexible. If you have longer text (for translations) or a bigger font (with dynamic type), 100 might not be enough. The accepted answer above solves for these. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: I added case when you use different `VStack` for `Text` and `TextField`

Comment: If you need flexible width check out  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58083886/4067700)

Comment: That Geometry Reader answer is just setting the width to 1/3 of the parent. That doesn't account for longer text, dynamic type, and different devices. The accepted answer above is close enough with tweaks and is the simplest solution I've found. Thanks.

Comment: @Jerry I have tested and even with the smallest screen 100 is perfect. In fact, even this ```.extraExtraExtraLarge```and iPhone SE (smallest screen) a width of 100 does the job

Comment: @LorisFoe it may be for the text that you have, but you don't know how long the text will be when translated to other languages. It may be much shorter or much longer. The solution should be flexible enough to handle various lengths.