# SwiftUI vertically misaligned text

Tags: swift, vertical-alignment, swiftui, beta

I have some vertically misaligned text and I don't know why...

The code:

```
struct IBANInputView: View {
    @State var securityDigits = ""
    @State var bankCode = ""
    @State var accountNumber = ""

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: onCountryButtonTapped, label: {
                Text("NL")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.purple)
            })
            TextField("00", text: $securityDigits)
                .fixedSize()
            TextField("BANK", text: $bankCode)
                .fixedSize()
            TextField("0000 0000 00", text: $accountNumber)
        }
    }

    func onCountryButtonTapped() {
        print("LOL")
    }
}
```

Preview:
[image: Misaligned text]

Frame inspector:
[image]

How come the text is vertically misaligned and how can I fix it?

Comment: Buttons and text fields are different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because by default your `HStack`'s vertical alignment is `.center`. I was able to achieve what you wanted by setting the `HStack`'s vertical alignment to `.firstTextBaseline` and then adjusting the button's vertical alignment slightly.

```
    HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
        Button(action: { print("haha") }, label: {
            Text("NL")
                .foregroundColor(Color.purple)
        })
            .alignmentGuide(.firstTextBaseline, computeValue: { return $0[.bottom] + 1.5 })

        TextField("00", text: $securityDigits)
            .fixedSize()
        TextField("BANK", text: $bankCode)
            .fixedSize()
        TextField("0000 0000 00", text: $accountNumber)
    }
```

Here I'm saying the first text baseline of the button is the button's `.bottom` and then moving that baseline up ever so slightly. You may have to experiment with values but I found this to be the most visually correct for your use-case.

[image]

It seems to me there's a bug in `Button` though by virtue of it not properly advertising the first text baseline in the button itself. This could potentially be cleaner by making a `.firstTextBaseline`-aware `Button` "subclass" that you can reuse elsewhere instead of making micro-adjustments everywhere.

Comment: Ah I see, this solves the issue, as I understand it this is a bug in SwiftUI beta leading to misaligned .firstTextBaseline with a Button for the HStack to use?

Comment: A `Button` can have any `View` as its `label` but even so, `Image` has a baseline (see SFSymobls) so to me it feels like `Button` should be forwarding its `label`'s baselines, but it does not appear to do that. I'm not sure if it's a technically a bug or not.

Comment: I added my answer and try to explain why this happens.

Answer (score 3):

#### Vertical misalignment

The `Text` inside the button does that. Try to use a constant text field.

```
Button(action: onCountryButtonTapped, label: {
    TextField("NL", text: .constant("NL"))
    .fixedSize()
    .disabled(true)
    .foregroundColor(Color.purple)
})
```

#### Size difference

The placeholder values of `TextField` have a different size. Once you enter text it should look the same.

Answer (score 2):

I added `alignment: .top` to `HStack`. And now vertical alignment is fine.

```swift
struct BankInputFieldDemo: View {
    @State var securityDigits = ""
    @State var bankCode = ""
    @State var accountNumber = ""

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Button(action: { print("haha") }, label: {
                Text("NL")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.purple)
            })

            TextField("00", text: $securityDigits)
                .fixedSize()
            TextField("BANK", text: $bankCode)
                .fixedSize()
            TextField("0000 0000 00", text: $accountNumber)
        }
    }
}
```

To see why this happened you can add `.border(Color.black)` to all elements. As you can notice `Text` has different height.

[image]

Or use `TextField` instead of `Text` like below

```swift
        HStack {
            Button(action: { print("haha") }, label: {
                TextField("", text: .constant("NL"))
                    .fixedSize()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.purple)
            })

            TextField("00", text: $securityDigits)
                .fixedSize()
            TextField("BANK", text: $bankCode)
                .fixedSize()
            TextField("0000 0000 00", text: $accountNumber)
        }
```

This issue is `Text` has not multiple size so SwiftUI can't align.
You can also add `.padding(.bottom, 1)` to `Text`

```swift
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: { print("haha") }, label: {
                    Text("NL")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.purple)
                        .padding(.bottom, 1)
                })

                TextField("00", text: $securityDigits)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                TextField("BANK", text: $bankCode)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                TextField("0000 0000 00", text: $accountNumber)
            }
        }
```

[image]
[image]

## More info

Check out [my video](https://youtu.be/ch_I6NRar-4).

## VStack

If you use `VStack` to align multiple elements look at my explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58391797/4067700)