# With Swiftui how we can create user form

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to create a form in which all textfield need to start from the same alignment, like in below image it does not start from the same alignment. First name, last name and Phone number all textFields are not aligned properly in a single vertical line.

```
VStack(){
        HStack(){
            Text("First Name")
            TextField("First name", text: $name).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
        HStack(){
            Text("Last Name")
            TextField("Last Name", text: $name).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
        HStack(){
            Text("Phone number")
            TextField("Phone number", text: $name).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
        Spacer()
    }.padding(10)
```

[image: Like in iamge]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GeometryReader` to access device size and `frame` to set fixed width for `Text`s. For example:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        HStack {
            Text("First Name").frame(width: geometry.size.width / 3)
            TextField("First name", text: self.$name).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
        HStack {
            Text("Last Name").frame(width: geometry.size.width / 3)
            TextField("Last Name", text: self.$name).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
        HStack{
            Text("Phone number").frame(width: geometry.size.width / 3)
            TextField("Phone number", text: self.$name).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
        Spacer()
    }.padding(10)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```swift
        VStack{
            HStack(){
                Text("First Name").frame(width: 120, alignment: .leading)
                TextField("First name", text: $name).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            }
            HStack(){
                Text("Last Name").frame(width: 120, alignment: .leading)
                TextField("Last Name", text: $name).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            }
            HStack{
                Text("Phone number").frame(width: 120, alignment: .leading)
                TextField("Phone number", text: $name).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            }
            Spacer()
        }.padding(10)
```

**or more flexible solution**

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State var name = ""
    @State var width: CGFloat = 0

    struct Label: ViewModifier {
        @Binding var width: CGFloat

        func getWidth(content: Content, proxy: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
            if proxy.size.width > width {
                RunLoop.main.perform {
                    self.width = proxy.size.width
                }
            }
            return content
        }

        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content.overlay(GeometryReader { proxy in
                self.getWidth(content: content, proxy: proxy)
            }).frame(minWidth: self.width, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center){
            HStack(){
                Text("First Name").modifier(Label(width: $width))
                TextField("First name", text: $name).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            }
            HStack(){
                Text("Last Name").modifier(Label(width: $width))
                TextField("Last Name", text: $name).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            }
            HStack{
                Text("Phone numbe").modifier(Label(width: $width))
                TextField("Phone number", text: $name).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            }

            Spacer()
        }.padding(10)
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the flexible solution when the width of all `Text` is equal to the width of the widest `Text`.

Comment: If i remove the line ```RunLoop.main.perform { in ... }``` the flexible solution  works (it takes the widest Text) otherwise it does not

Answer (score 2):

This will align your TextFields:

```
VStack {
    HStack {
        HStack {
            Text("First Name")
            Spacer()
        }
        TextField("First name", text: $name)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    }
    HStack {
        HStack {
            Text("Last Name")
            Spacer()
        }
        TextField("Last Name", text: $name)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    }
    HStack {
        HStack {
            Text("Phone number")
            Spacer()
        }
        TextField("Phone number", text: $name)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    }
    Spacer()
}   .padding(10)
```